# Fabric equivalent of try finally

Tags: python, fabric

In the eventuality that Fabric exits cleanly or not, I need to execute a bunch of clean-up tasks (mostly **delete temp files and folders**).

How can I achieve this with Fabric?

Answer (score 5):

Put something like this in your fabfile:

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings

def task_name():
    # commands that are not expected to fail
    ...
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        # commands that might fail
        ...
    clean_up()
```

You may even want to give the entire task the `warn_only=True` treatment, if you don't care:

```
@with_settings(warn_only=True)
def task_name():
    ...
```

([more info](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings))

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the new execute() and wrap that in a try/except or just look at the return codes from your run()s.